# Changing pandas dataframe columns from int to string and saving as string csv

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv

I have a pandas dataframe which is initially columns of type int. I change the type to string and then save it using `to_csv`. But in the csv I am saving, I am not getting data in the form `'1', '2',..`, instead its like `1,2,..`.

This is what I am doing:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(3, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  2  3  0  4
1  4  0  3  4
2  4  4  4  3
>>> print(df.dtypes)
A    int64
B    int64
C    int64
D    int64
dtype: object
>>> df = df.astype(str)
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  2  3  0  4
1  4  0  3  4
2  4  4  4  3

>>> print(df.dtypes)
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
dtype: object
>>> df.to_csv('./df.csv', index = False)
```

When I check the saved file I get the following

```
➜ head -2 df.csv
A,B,C,D
2,3,0,4
```

I want it to be like the following:

```
➜ head -2 df.csv
A,B,C,D
"2","3","0","4"
```

Comment: You can just add the quoting param: df.to_csv('./df.csv', index=False, quoting=1)

Comment: And you don't want quotes around the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `quoting` to `to_csv`:

```
import csv
df.to_csv('a.csv', index=False,, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

# or without importing csv module
df.to_csv('a.csv', index=False,, quoting=2)
```

You can even do with the original data frame with `quoting=1`:

```
df.to_csv('a.csv' quoting=1)
```

Output:

```
"A","B","C","D"
"2","3","0","4"
"4","0","3","4"
"4","4","4","3"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: '"' + str(x) + '"')
```